# Combinatorics pigeonhole principle question.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

There are $n$ people at a meeting, each of whom chooses $3$ distinct numbers between $1$ and $11.$ 
 
 $\quad({\sf a})$ What is the smallest value of $n$ which guarantees that at least two people choose numbers which sum to the same total? 
 
 $\quad({\sf b})$ What is the smallest value of $n$ which guarantees that there is a number which is chosen by at least two people? 
 
 $\quad({\sf c})$ What is the smallest value of $n$ which guarantees that at least two people choose the same set of three numbers?

I get that I need to use pigeonhole principle, but I don't get where and how?

Answer (score 1):

A start: The smallest possible sum of three is $6$, the biggest is $30$, and all sums in between are achievable. That gives $25$ possible sums. Call these the pigeonholes. How many pigeons do we need to make sure there are at least two in some pigeonhole?

Comment: 7, 31 and 26? i think i am wrong though

Comment: We need $26$ people at the party to make absolutely sure that there are (at least) two people with the same sum.

Comment: why? and have do you achieve this?

Comment: Do make sure that you can see that there are $25$ achievable sums of three distinct numbers in the range from $1$ to $11$. If there are $25$ people at the party, it is conceivable that they might all have different sums. But if we have $26$ or more people, then since there are only $25$ different possible sums, there must be at least two people with the same sum. A similar but easier to grasp example. May has $31$ days. We have invited people to a party for people born in May. What is the smallest number of people we must invite to make sure at least two have the same birthday? answer: $32$.

Comment: Yeah i get it and thank you, could you help with the last two parts please. would part be 12?

Comment: I would like to wait for a while, to give you time to attack the remaining two problems, now that you see what's going on. The reasoning will be of the same general kind as in a).

Comment: SO part b would be 12?

Comment: The answer to b) is not $12$, it is (quite a bit) smaller than that.

Comment: could you explain please, i am really struggling with this topic?

Comment: would the answer it 3?

Comment: The people at the party are A, B, C, D, E, and so on. Imagine A choosing $3$, then B, and so on. What is the first time that somebody will be for sure forced to pick a number already chosen?

Comment: I think you have the general idea, but if you think about it some more, you will see it is $4$.

Comment: it would have to be the 4th person

Comment: So $4$ is the smallest number of people that makes sure that at least two people share a number.

Comment: yeah because if A (123) B(456) C(789) D(11 10 and a number already used)

Comment: Or to put it an equivalent way, if A, B, C have all chosen different numbers, they have used up nine of them, so D *must*  pick a number already chosen.

Comment: would the last part would it be 11C3 then +1?

Comment: Yes, you've got it.

Comment: Really? ihave the answer?

Comment: Yes you do. What is uob? University of Bath?

Comment: No university of Birmingham. Sorry i am really surprised, i hardly understand pigeonhole principle.

Comment: It takes working through a number of problems to get fully used to it.

Comment: You are welcome.